# What used to work in Angular no longer is in 14.2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I generate a new component and I get this:

```
Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.
Argument of type 'ClassDecoratorContext<typeof DatatablesMasterComponent>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | symbol | undefined'.ts(1238)
```

[image: Angular Components aren't working]

This, for the `<mat-card>` is throwing an error even though `MatCardModule` is imported along with all the other Material components and `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` and `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` is there too.

```
'mat-card' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)
contacts.component.ts(26, 7): Error occurs in the template of component
```

Then, this:

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.ngtsc(-998002)
calg-contacts.component.ts(26, 7): Error occurs in the template of component ContactsComponent.
```

This is my `<form>` in HTML:

```html
<form id="contactForm" [formGroup]="ContactForm" ngForm #ContactForm (ngSubmit)="submitForm(ContactForm, $event)">
```

and in my .ts file, I have this:

```js
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit, AfterViewInit {


  @ViewChild('ContactForm', { static: false }) ContactForm: NgForm;
```

this used to be and worked:

```js
  @ViewChild('ContactForm', null) ContactForm: NgForm;
```

but if I fix it with the new {static: false} the HTML breaks and FormGroup can't be found.
If I use NULL, the HTML is fixed but the .ts file throws an error, but even with the error both ways, it compiles fine with zero errors, again, which makes no sense.

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "module": "es2020",
/// but now THESE are throwing errors... so I remove them
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": false,
///
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "src/types",
      "mocha"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": [
        "./node_modules/@angular/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "enableIvy": true
  }
}
```

This is a the new error:

```
Option 'emitDecoratorMetadata' cannot be specified without specifying option 'experimentalDecorators'.ts
Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files.

See more: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#emitDecoratorMetadata
```

I've read the URL and it's all React.

What is going on? I've deleted `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and did a cache clean, etc.

Here's my Angular, Node and NPM versions

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.12
Node: 16.14.2
Package Manager: npm 8.5.1
OS: win32 x64

 

Angular: 14.2.12
... animations, cli, common, compiler, core
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server

 

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.12
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.12
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.12
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.12
@angular/cdk                    14.2.7
@angular/compiler-cli           14.3.0
@angular/elements               14.3.0
@angular/flex-layout            14.0.0-beta.41
@angular/forms                  14.3.0
@angular/language-service       14.3.0
@angular/localize               14.3.0
@angular/material               14.2.7
@angular/platform-browser       14.3.0
@angular/router                 14.3.0
@schematics/angular             14.2.12
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.7.4
webpack                         5.88.2
```

Comment: Check for migrations. I do think that v14 did change the import paths of **all** angular-material packages.

Comment: Where would I check for that? Forgive my ignorance